# Saving/ serializing/ dumping a deleted object and then restoring again

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails to save/ serialize/ dump an object with all its deeply nested associated objects in a database table and then restore it again? I would like to turn off auto-increment ids before restoring and then turn auto increment back on after the objects have been restored?

Our users sometimes delete objects they did not intend to and would like to see them restored. We cannot keep deleted objects around in our active database as they have many associated objects (many belongs_to and has_many relationships with objects that in turn have many such relationships again).

Thanks in advance to the SO community.

Comment: You could use JSON obj to store the object with all the associations, then restore them with a recursive function. I've saw in best practices to turn off or make objects unavailable thru flags, you could add an expiration date and them not retrievable.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the object with associations to JSON ([or XML](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_xml)):

```
user.as_json(include: { posts: {
                           include: { comments: {
                                          only: :body } },
                           only: :title } })
```

Example of produced JSON:

```
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#      "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true,
#      "posts" => [ { "comments" => [ { "body" => "1st post!" }, { "body" => "Second!" } ],
#                     "title" => "Welcome to the weblog" },
#                   { "comments" => [ { "body" => "Don't think too hard" } ],
#                     "title" => "So I was thinking" } ] }
```

Taken from last example for [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

And this [post](http://eigenjoy.com/2008/08/11/activerecord-from_xml-and-from_json-part-2/) is about unmarshalling nested models.
Looks like the code provided there will allow you to restore object with all associations by calling:

```
user = User.from_json user_with_associations_as_json_string
```